# fastest way to read an f06 file (Nastran) with matlab

Tags: matlab, nastran

I have to read several file of results from Nastran with MATLAB. 
I need to import the information about the displacement vector, which is located in the middle of the file, (but I know the line where the section about displacements starts and ends.).

Those files are formatted as follows:

- They are divided in "pages" with a fixed number of row per page
- Each page has a header, which I do not need to import
- Data columns have fixed width
  (Below an example of "a page" of the file )

I have written a function in matlab, but it is extremely slow, and this process is the bottleneck of my code. (Those files are very big and I need to process a lot of them): I'm searching the fastest way to read them.

Have you some ideas?

Thank you
Edit: I have added my code

```
function [TIME,T1,T2,T3,R1,R2,R3]=importdisp(D,L,cst,cst2,filename)
%D first row of the section
%L last row+1 of the section
page=floor((L-D)/cst);
q=zeros((page)*cst2,1);
TIME=q;T1=q;T2=q;T3=q;R1=q;R2=q; R3=q;

for i=0:page-1
    startRow=D+i*cst;
    endRow=startRow+cst-1;
    qq=(1+i*cst2:(i+1)*cst2);
    [TIME(qq),~,T1(qq),T2(qq),T3(qq),R1(qq),R2(qq),R3(qq)] = importfile2(filename, startRow, endRow);
end
i=page;
startRow=D+i*57;
endRow=L-1;
[aTIME,~,aT1,aT2,aT3,aR1,aR2,aR3] = importfile2(filename, startRow, endRow);
TIME=[TIME;aTIME];
T1=[T1;aT1];
T2=[T2;aT2];
T3=[T3;aT3];

function [TIME,TYPE,T1,T2,T3,R1,R2,R3] = importfile2(filename, startRow, endRow)   

%% Read columns of data as strings:
% For more information, see the TEXTSCAN documentation.
formatSpec = '   %12f     %*s     %13f     %13f     %13f     %13f     %13f     %13f';

%% Open the text file.
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow-startRow-6,'HeaderLines',startRow+6, 'ReturnOnError', false);

fclose(fileID);

TIME = cell2mat(dataArray(1));
TYPE = [];%
T1 = cell2mat(dataArray(2));
T2 = cell2mat(dataArray(3));
T3 = cell2mat(dataArray(4));
R1 = cell2mat(dataArray(5));
R2 = cell2mat(dataArray(6));
R3 = cell2mat(dataArray(7));
    R1=[R1;aR1];
R2=[R2;aR2];
R3=[R3;aR3];







1    MSC.NASTRAN JOB CREATED ON 23-JUL-13 AT 11:37:55                          JULY  30, 2013  MSC.NASTRAN 11/25/11   PAGE   375
     TIME_DIPENDENT                                                                                                                 
0                                                                                                SUBCASE 1                          
      POINT-ID =        51
                                             D I S P L A C E M E N T   V E C T O R

       TIME       TYPE          T1             T2             T3             R1             R2             R3
   1.010000E+00     G      3.575517E-05   0.0           -2.498832E-05   0.0           -1.368603E-06   0.0
   1.010200E+00     G      3.615527E-05   0.0            5.931119E-05   0.0            2.523460E-08   0.0
   1.010400E+00     G      3.643431E-05   0.0            1.400531E-04   0.0            1.428176E-06   0.0
   1.010600E+00     G      3.690420E-05   0.0            2.124308E-04   0.0            1.886763E-06   0.0
   1.010800E+00     G      3.727554E-05   0.0            2.720885E-04   0.0            1.029395E-06   0.0
   1.011000E+00     G      3.753303E-05   0.0            3.154415E-04   0.0           -5.155680E-07   0.0
   1.011200E+00     G      3.799178E-05   0.0            3.399170E-04   0.0           -1.612602E-06   0.0
   1.011400E+00     G      3.847007E-05   0.0            3.440528E-04   0.0           -1.544716E-06   0.0
   1.011600E+00     G      3.878193E-05   0.0            3.275930E-04   0.0           -3.747878E-07   0.0
   1.011800E+00     G      3.927647E-05   0.0            2.914786E-04   0.0            1.095575E-06   0.0
   1.012000E+00     G      3.994424E-05   0.0            2.378519E-04   0.0            1.759643E-06   0.0
   1.012200E+00     G      4.034076E-05   0.0            1.699633E-04   0.0            1.095494E-06   0.0
   1.012400E+00     G      4.074808E-05   0.0            9.188905E-05   0.0           -3.884768E-07   0.0
   1.012600E+00     G      4.135053E-05   0.0            8.304626E-06   0.0           -1.629274E-06   0.0
   1.012800E+00     G      4.170949E-05   0.0           -7.576412E-05   0.0           -1.752396E-06   0.0
   1.013000E+00     G      4.199858E-05   0.0           -1.552350E-04   0.0           -6.461957E-07   0.0
   1.013200E+00     G      4.248216E-05   0.0           -2.252832E-04   0.0            8.903658E-07   0.0
   1.013400E+00     G      4.278283E-05   0.0           -2.817524E-04   0.0            1.804066E-06   0.0
   1.013600E+00     G      4.301732E-05   0.0           -3.213745E-04   0.0            1.573536E-06   0.0
   1.013800E+00     G      4.358916E-05   0.0           -3.417496E-04   0.0            3.442360E-07   0.0
   1.014000E+00     G      4.405503E-05   0.0           -3.414665E-04   0.0           -1.139860E-06   0.0
   1.014200E+00     G      4.437157E-05   0.0           -3.203563E-04   0.0           -1.834472E-06   0.0
   1.014400E+00     G      4.499020E-05   0.0           -2.795874E-04   0.0           -1.277272E-06   0.0
   1.014600E+00     G      4.558231E-05   0.0           -2.215368E-04   0.0            2.333646E-08   0.0
   1.014800E+00     G      4.597261E-05   0.0           -1.495850E-04   0.0            1.129674E-06   0.0
   1.015000E+00     G      4.643634E-05   0.0           -6.810582E-05   0.0            1.298742E-06   0.0
   1.015200E+00     G      4.685981E-05   0.0            1.765095E-05   0.0            4.973296E-07   0.0
   1.015400E+00     G      4.722315E-05   0.0            1.022117E-04   0.0           -5.859554E-07   0.0
   1.015600E+00     G      4.764707E-05   0.0            1.804387E-04   0.0           -1.191458E-06   0.0
   1.015800E+00     G      4.799638E-05   0.0            2.476246E-04   0.0           -9.108963E-07   0.0
   1.016000E+00     G      4.831509E-05   0.0            2.995918E-04   0.0            1.032815E-07   0.0
   1.016200E+00     G      4.872533E-05   0.0            3.330215E-04   0.0            1.085160E-06   0.0
   1.016400E+00     G      4.917991E-05   0.0            3.459135E-04   0.0            1.281773E-06   0.0
   1.016600E+00     G      4.956298E-05   0.0            3.376274E-04   0.0            5.597767E-07   0.0
   1.016800E+00     G      4.989865E-05   0.0            3.085430E-04   0.0           -5.647819E-07   0.0
   1.017000E+00     G      5.048857E-05   0.0            2.602277E-04   0.0           -1.257802E-06   0.0
   1.017200E+00     G      5.116086E-05   0.0            1.957408E-04   0.0           -1.047838E-06   0.0
   1.017400E+00     G      5.149745E-05   0.0            1.192598E-04   0.0           -1.662111E-07   0.0
   1.017600E+00     G      5.192366E-05   0.0            3.549325E-05   0.0            7.763596E-07   0.0
   1.017800E+00     G      5.251750E-05   0.0           -5.053262E-05   0.0            1.131500E-06   0.0
   1.018000E+00     G      5.280536E-05   0.0           -1.334662E-04   0.0            6.140833E-07   0.0
   1.018200E+00     G      5.301622E-05   0.0           -2.081115E-04   0.0           -3.166196E-07   0.0
   1.018400E+00     G      5.345660E-05   0.0           -2.701173E-04   0.0           -8.439085E-07   0.0
   1.018600E+00     G      5.390675E-05   0.0           -3.158737E-04   0.0           -5.923507E-07   0.0
   1.018800E+00     G      5.422348E-05   0.0           -3.423101E-04   0.0            1.950982E-07   0.0
   1.019000E+00     G      5.467689E-05   0.0           -3.474040E-04   0.0            9.392950E-07   0.0
   1.019200E+00     G      5.521453E-05   0.0           -3.307139E-04   0.0            1.020770E-06   0.0
   1.019400E+00     G      5.565249E-05   0.0           -2.932987E-04   0.0            2.693299E-07   0.0
   1.019600E+00     G      5.617935E-05   0.0           -2.372591E-04   0.0           -8.091097E-07   0.0
   1.019800E+00     G      5.678378E-05   0.0           -1.657268E-04   0.0           -1.504755E-06   0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39033-triangular-mesh-conversion-from-matlab-to-nastran-ascii-format-and-vice-versa?

Comment: I have added my code. It takes 20-25 s to import 5000 timestep.

Answer (score 1):

Nastran f06 files are formatted to provide adequate readibility for users. For programming purposes at the other hand, there is a better option in my opinion. It is the punch file (.pch). It contains all the results in a fixed-length text table format. You do not have to deal with page breaks, empty lines or repeatitive identifiers at each page like you do in an f06 file. The good thing is that once you have achieved a code that reads some data successfully, you can just use almost the same pattern in order to read other kind of data because the only thing that changes the title and the row number. You have to examine a little to get into it anyway...

The punch file must be requested by the BDF file. For example if your request is:

```
DISPLACEMENT (PRINT) = ALL
```

then you add a "PUNCH"

```
DISPLACEMENT (PUNCH,PRINT) = ALL
```

and it will generate the pch file as well as the f06 file.

Answer (score 0):

Old post but whatever.  The answer is don't use Matlab, it is very very slow at parsing text files.  It just is. It's optimized for matrix operations which reading text files rarely is.  I had code which used to take minutes to read in large f06 files in matlab. When ported to python took less than 100 milliseconds to run.

As the other example suggested punch file are more appropriate for this work.